# How to target watch stream to limited sets of data?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I want to use Mongodb change streams to watch updates on specific sets of data.

For example likes

```
await Match.updateOne({matchId: 79949451}, {$set: {statusType: 'inprogress'}}).exec();

const pipeline = [{ $match: { matchId: 79949451}}];
Match.watch(pipeline).on('change', data => console.log(data));

await Match.updateOne({matchId: 79949451}, {$set: {statusType: 'finished'}}).exec();
```

This doesn't seems to work. StatusType get updated, but i don't get the log.

But if I removed the pipeline , i see the log

```
await Match.updateOne({matchId: 79949451}, {$set: {statusType: 'inprogress'}}).exec();

Match.watch().on('change', data => console.log(data));

await Match.updateOne({matchId: 79949451}, {$set: {statusType: 'finished'}}).exec();
```

Upto what I read and understand that pipeline only work on updated fields and something have to do with `fullDocument`.

How can I make this to work ? Is there anything simple I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$match` should be this:

```
const pipeline = [{ $match: { 'fullDocument.matchId': 79949451}}];
```

Because [change stream output](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/#change-stream-output) is not the same as output of a direct query operation, you must reference your document fields through `fullDocument`. Don't forget to add `{fullDocument: 'updateLookup'}` to the watch options.

```
Match.watch(pipeline, {fullDocument: 'updateLookup'}).on(...
```

Note: to anyone unfamiliar with this syntax, OP is using Mongoose.js.